# I would like to center the icons while keeping the panel background extended?

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-panel, dash-to-dock

Regarding the dash-to-panel extension build in to Ubuntu, I would like to be able to center the icons in the panel while keeping it extended across the screen.

One method that I have found to center the icons is to disable panel mode, but then that collapses the whole panel and leaves gaps around the outer edge of it. I understand that this may not be possible with the current version (22.04LTS), but if so, I would like to see it added in the future.

I also installed dconf, but did not see any obvious way to achieve what I'm going for, but perhaps I'm missing it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A way to achieve this with `dash-to-panel v56`, on `gnome 43.6`:

- go to the dash-to-panel extension settings
- on the "Position" tab, scroll down to the position and visibility table
  [image]

  - make sure the "Left box" is visible and centered (or "Monitor centered", whatever you prefer)
  - "Taskbar" must also be visible

...looks like this on my screen:
[image]